# Как получить доступ к файлам из локального html файла

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, google-chrome, pwa

Есть желание сделать локальное безсерверное приложение, содержащее в себе мелкие прикладные инструменты.
Запускается оно через команду:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome_proxy.exe" --app="file:///foo/bar/index.html"`

Проблемы начинаются при попытке подключить `manifest.json`:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json">
```

браузер ругается и файл не грузит.
Есть ли вообще возможность сделать что-то подобное?

Comment: какие такие `прикладные инструменты`?

Comment: это к вопросу не относится.

Comment: Из всей информации, которую вы дали полезного только то, как вы запускаете ваше приложение. А зачем это делать вообще - это к вопросу не относится.

Comment: вопрос в том как из html файла открытого локально через chrome_proxy.exe грузить другие локальные фалы в том числе manifest.json, какая разница что в конечном счете будет делать приложение?

Comment: есть вариант реализации приложения как PWA, что бы такое приложение можно было запускать с ярлыка в отдельном окне браузера, но без лишних элементов интерфейса т.е. как обычное приложение, и без целого браузера с собой, как в Electron, необходимы web-сервер, ssl сертификат и доменное имя. Так вот т.к. я делаю приложение только для себя и своих знакомых, и не хочу заморачиваться с организацией хостинга, покупкой доменного имени, покупкой сертификата и т.д. мне проще запускать организованное через локальный HTML файл PWA. И проблема только в том, что не удается загрузить manifest.json.

Comment: Так там не только `manifest.json` не будет работать. Это только первое ограничение, с которым вы столкнулись. Потом выясните, что так вообще ничего работать не будет. Я же и пытаюсь выяснить какие возможности от браузера вам нужны, чтобы понять реально ли все это...

Comment: как выяснилось скрипты и стили грузятся, проблема пока только с manifest.json.
предполагаю что могут возникнуть затруднения с разрешениями, но в них пока нет потребности.